# Santo Estêvão ou São Estêvão? Quando utilizar São e Santo?

Tags: gramática

É muito comum ouvirmos, na Igreja Católica, o nome de alguns Santos. Porém percebo que há uma variação nos nomes masculinos — coisa que não ocorre nos femininos.

**Exemplo Masculinos:**

> **São** José
> **São** João
> **São** Pedro
> **Santo** Antônio
> **Santo** Expedito
> **Santo** André

**Exemplo Femininos:**

> **Santa** Maria
> **Santa** Ana
> **Santa** Terezinha
> **Santa** Bárbara
> **Santa** Luzia
> **Santa** Joana

Ao acessar o site do [Convento da Penha](http://conventodapenha.org.br/santo-estevao-primeiro-martir-da-igreja-26-de-dezembro/), vi que eles utilizam "Santo Estêvão"

> ***Santo** Estêvão foi o primeiro que, para seguir o Mestre Divino, sacrificou a própria vida.*

Na oração, porém, aparece "São Estêvão"

> *Deus de amor e de bondade, que possamos aprender de **São** Estevão a humildade e o carinho pelos pobres (...)*

Afinal de contas, qual o termo correto? Há uma regra, na gramática, que defina qual termo usar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pesquisando em vários lugares, a regra é:

1. Nomes Masculinos iniciados com **consoantes** que não **H**, usa-se sempre **São** (São João, São José)
2. Nomes Masculinos iniciados com **vogais** ou **H** (provavelmente quando não é pronunciado), usa-se sempre **Santo** (Santo Antônio, Santo Estêvão)
3. Nomes Femininos, sempre usa-se **Santa** (Santa Maria, Santa Ana).

Lembrando que o **São** é uma abreviatura de **Santo** e utilizado devido a sonoridade. Há também algumas abreviações de **Santa**, que lembro da SantAna (Santa Ana).

Mas não há consenso no São Estêvão ou Santo Estêvão, segundo o **Sua Lingua**.

> Houaiss menciona SANTO Tirso (em vez de São Tirso); eu acrescento SÃO
>   Estêvão (em vez de SANTO Estevão).

Por fim, com as informações encontradas e também citando os próprios trechos mencionados por ti, acredito que as duas formas estão corretas.

Fontes:

1. [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/sao--santo/8203)
2. [Super Interessante - Mundo Estranho](https://super.abril.com.br/mundo-estranho/por-que-o-nome-de-alguns-santos-comeca-com-sao/)
3. [Sua Língua - São ou Santo](http://sualingua.com.br/2009/05/08/sao-ou-santo/)

Comment: Talvez o critério seja fonético. Em Portugal, foneticamente, *Estêvão* começa com consoante: "Chtêvão".

Comment: @Jacinto, pensei que poderia ser fonetico, já que São e Santo e por esse motivo. Mas não lembrei do chiado português. Estou morando em Lisboa, mas sou Gaúcho, então, não falo chiado, por isso, não lembro desses detalhes...

Comment: É uma possibilidade, mas não tenho a certeza. Vi "São Estêvão" em publicações brasileiras. Aliás o próprio Cláudio Moreno mencionou isso. Creio que mesmo os brasileiros que chiam o s pronuncia "Ichtêvão". É possível que noutros tempos em Portugal se pronunciasse "Stêvão". Já vi coisas assim, "sperança" e isso.

Comment: Vi num site, o qual não me recordo, que, devido a usucapião do erro, a gramática aceita ambas construções (São e Santo) para alguns nomes. Como citado pelo @Jacinto, [é possível usar o critério fonético](http://catolicismo.com.br/materia/materia.cfm/idmat/1ACD5711-E838-4BF9-95D9197E313E9CCE/mes/Fevereiro2004), por exemplo: ***Santo** Tomás* / ***São** Tomás*. Nesta construção temos uma *cacofonia* e poderia ser ouvido como *Santo Más*.